# find out an IP accessing my ubuntu server (web server using apache)

Tags: 16.04

I'm a newbie.

is there any command or anyone know  to get all the real IP that connect / access my server ???

i'm using apache for my website server.

thank you

Comment: you can check your apache server logs at `/var/log/apache2/access.log`

Comment: I get the  IP local cause of nat in my network. is there any way to get real IP public that access my server??

Comment: NAT is usually setup to work the other way around, meaning your LAN address gets NAT'd to your external WAN facing IP address. You will need to describe your network setup in much more detail before we can help.

Comment: Yes I mean like that.

Comment: will try to describe. So my server is behind the router with a nat and all the server get an ip public after fowarding  from the router.

Comment: Then look in `/var/log/apache2/access.log`, as in the first comment.

Comment: Yes I tried . But it show me local IP that I get from my router. Then I'm try to do the same thing on my vps that I put on digital ocean its different. It show me my ip public.